# Find pattern between special characters

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, pattern-matching

I need a Sed/awk command to print the data between special charactes provided the pattern match should present in between special characters ({ & })

I have got a file which contains

```
define service {
host_name                       dns_vips
service_description             Multi Lookup 
use                             standard_service_template
active_checks_enabled           1
passive_checks_enabled          1
notifications_enabled           1
contact_groups                  mailgrp
max_check_attempts              3
normal_check_interval           5
retry_check_interval            1
notification_interval           10
check_period                    24x7
notification_period             24x7
notification_options            w,r,c
}
define service {
host_name                       dns_vips1
service_description             Multi Lookup 2  
use                             standard_service_template
active_checks_enabled           1
passive_checks_enabled          1
notifications_enabled           1
contact_groups                  mailgrp1
max_check_attempts              3
normal_check_interval           5
retry_check_interval            1
notification_interval           10
check_period                    24x7
notification_period             24x7
notification_options            w,r,c
}
```

I need data between `{` and `}` when the service description matches Multi Lookup

Comment: can you provide a sample of expected output ?

Comment: So, in this example, you want both entries to be printed, right? Can you also have text that is not within `{ }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed '
    /{/{            #starts next code block if line include «{» 
        :1          #set mark point 
        /}/!{       #execute if pattern (collected lines) do not include «}»
            N       #add next line to the pattern space
            b1      #return to marked point
            }       #end of second (inner) block of code
        }           #end of first block of code 
    /Multi Lookup/p #prints pattern (collected lines) if it has «Multi Lookup»
    d               #clean pattern (start from the beginning)
' file
```

Comment: @harish If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, all of your data are inside `{ }` and you want to print those records whose `service_description` matches `Multi Lookup`. If so, you can use a cool `perl` trick.

Perl has a "paragraph mode" where records (lines) are defined by blank lines. So, if you add a newline character after every `}`, you can simply do:

```
sed 's/}/}\n/' file | perl -00ne '/service_description\s*Multi Lookup/ && print'
```

The `sed` adds a `\n` after every `}`. Perl's `-00` will turn on paragraph mode and `-ne` will cause it to read each input line (here, line means paragraph) and apply the script given by `-e` to it. The result is that records whose `service_description` matches `Multi Lookup` are printed.

Alternatively, you could set perl's record separator (what defines a "line"), the variable `$/`, in the script itself and avoid the `sed` step

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{$/="}\n"}/service_description\s*Multi Lookup/ && print' file
```

Comment: Stuff like this is why I need to learn `perl`.  Thanks for sharing.  :)  Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't this break if there happens to be an extra newline, say, after the `{`?

Comment: @Wildcard if there are two newlines after the `{` (one to end the line end then an empty one, then yes, it will. I am assuming (perhaps incorrectly) that this won't be the case.

Comment: Can also set `$/` with a `BEGIN` block rather than needing to `sed` in front.

Comment: @Sobrique I find this both clearer and shorter than using a BEGIN block but how is that relevant? The `$/` is set by the `-00` flag, not by `sed`. The `sed` is just adding an extra newline so that can work.

Comment: Because then you don't need to use `sed` to insert a newline, you can `$/` on `}` (Edited my suggestion accordingly).

Comment: @Sobrique ah, yes indeed, good point. Answer edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly straightforward with e.g. `perl` if that's an option. Parse the record into key-value pairs, and then extract/match the field you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

#set record separator to 'end bracket'. 
local $/ = '}';

#iterate our data based on that delimiter. 
#note - <> is a magic filehandle, in that it reads either pipe
#from stdin, or a file argument specified on command like (e.g. like awk/sed)
while (<>) {
    #extract key-value pairs with a multi line regex for this 'block'
    my %fields = m/(\w+)\s+(.*)$/gm;

    print Dumper \%fields; #to see what we captured for debugging. 

    #test a particular field against a regex. Note - this matches 
    #both in your example. 
    if ( $fields{service_description} =~ m/Multi Lookup/ ) {
        print "This record matches\n";
    }
}
```

Each record in the above gets put into fields, and is a `perl` `hash` containing:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'define' => 'service {',
          'use' => 'standard_service_template',
          'check_period' => '24x7',
          'host_name' => 'dns_vips',
          'service_description' => 'Multi Lookup ',
          'active_checks_enabled' => '1',
          'passive_checks_enabled' => '1',
          'notification_interval' => '10',
          'notification_period' => '24x7',
          'contact_groups' => 'mailgrp',
          'max_check_attempts' => '3',
          'notifications_enabled' => '1',
          'notification_options' => 'w,r,c',
          'normal_check_interval' => '5',
          'retry_check_interval' => '1'
        };
```

This could be compressed to a one liner if desired I'm sure, but you'd have to be a bit more specific about what you're actually wanting as output.

e.g.

```
 perl -ne 'BEGIN { $/ = "}" } %f = m/(\w+)\s+(.*)$/gm; print if $f{service_description} =~ m/Multi Lookup/'
```

Or perhaps an even simpler:

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN { $/ = "}" } print if m/service_description.*Multi Lookup/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun I tried doing it as a `vim` one-liner.  (Who ever heard of such a thing, right?)

```
vim -c 'g/service_description\s\+Multi Lookup\s\+$/?{?+,/}/-w! >> outputfile.txt' -c 'q!' inputfile.txt
```

What this does: Finds each line that contains `service_description` [whitespace] `Multi Lookup` [whitespace, end of line], and outputs all the lines from the preceding `{` to the following `}` for each match, not including the lines containing the `{` and `}` characters, and writing the output lines to `outputfile.txt`.  It then exits without modifying `inputfile.txt`.

I couldn't tell if you wanted `Multi Lookup 2` to match; if so, remove the `\s\+$` after `Multi Lookup`.

If you wanted to include the lines with the curly brackets as well, remove the `+` after the `?{?` and the `-` after the `/}/`.

Probably overkill since you can just use `sed`, but it was good practice for me.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -e '.put if /service_description \h+ Multi \h Lookup/ for slurp.comb(/^^ define \h service \h \{  <-[ } ]>* \} $$ /);'  file

#OR (more simply)

~$ raku -e '.put if /DESIRED_MATCH/ for slurp.comb( / ^^START <-[ END_char ]>* END$$ /);'
```

Above is an answer written in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Reading the code from right-to-left, Raku's `slurp` reads the file into memory all at once, and `comb` can be thought of as the inverse of `split` since it ***selects*** for blocks of matching text (instead of destroying same). This approach makes the selection insensitive to extraneous characters _between_the desired blocks of text.

The `^^` start-of-line and `$$` end-of-line assertions are used to provide specificity, and the block-internal characters are defined using `<-[ } ]>*`, a negative-character class comprising (zero-or-more of) any character except `}` closing curly brace. The `comb`ed elements are iterated through with `for`, and `if` the desired match is found (`\h` stands for horizontal whitespace), the element is out`put`.

Given the OP's input file (changing the second curly-block to provide a negative control), we get the following output:

Sample Input:

```
define service {
host_name                       dns_vips
service_description             Multi Lookup 
use                             standard_service_template
active_checks_enabled           1
passive_checks_enabled          1
notifications_enabled           1
contact_groups                  mailgrp
max_check_attempts              3
normal_check_interval           5
retry_check_interval            1
notification_interval           10
check_period                    24x7
notification_period             24x7
notification_options            w,r,c
}
define service {
host_name                       dns_vips1
service_description             Single Lookup
use                             standard_service_template
active_checks_enabled           1
passive_checks_enabled          1
notifications_enabled           1
contact_groups                  mailgrp1
max_check_attempts              3
normal_check_interval           5
retry_check_interval            1
notification_interval           10
check_period                    24x7
notification_period             24x7
notification_options            w,r,c
}
```

Sample Output:

```
define service {
host_name                       dns_vips
service_description             Multi Lookup 
use                             standard_service_template
active_checks_enabled           1
passive_checks_enabled          1
notifications_enabled           1
contact_groups                  mailgrp
max_check_attempts              3
normal_check_interval           5
retry_check_interval            1
notification_interval           10
check_period                    24x7
notification_period             24x7
notification_options            w,r,c
}
```

To simplify the search regex used by `comb`, we can use Raku's `~` tilde notation for finding matched delimiters (curlies, brackets, parens, etc.), giving us `[ \{ ~ \} <-[ } ]>* ]` instead. Also, if we want to look at Raku's internal representation of the `slurp`ed data, drop the `if` conditional and use `.raku.put`, like so:

```
~$ raku -e '.raku.put for slurp.comb(/^^ define \h service \h [ \{ ~ \} <-[ } ]>* ]  $$/);'  file
"define service \{\nhost_name                       dns_vips\nservice_description             Multi Lookup \nuse                             standard_service_template\nactive_checks_enabled           1\npassive_checks_enabled          1\nnotifications_enabled           1\ncontact_groups                  mailgrp\nmax_check_attempts              3\nnormal_check_interval           5\nretry_check_interval            1\nnotification_interval           10\ncheck_period                    24x7\nnotification_period             24x7\nnotification_options            w,r,c\n}"
"define service \{\nhost_name                       dns_vips1\nservice_description             Single Lookup\nuse                             standard_service_template\nactive_checks_enabled           1\npassive_checks_enabled          1\nnotifications_enabled           1\ncontact_groups                  mailgrp1\nmax_check_attempts              3\nnormal_check_interval           5\nretry_check_interval            1\nnotification_interval           10\ncheck_period                    24x7\nnotification_period             24x7\nnotification_options            w,r,c\n}"
```

If `slurp`ing the file in all at once is problematic, you could try `lines.join("\n")` instead, which *might* be more memory efficient. Also, this answer could be re-written using Raku's `%` hash data-structures, making analysis of multiple different key-value pairs more efficient as well.

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Tilde_for_nesting_structures
https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org